# Break apart an array in _Post

Tags: php, post

I have a form where arrays are being past in $_POST. I understand _POST variables are in an array  themselves, so this is an array within an array? How do I reference them in PHP - the simlest way?

Here is the POST data and the arrays are "name" and "address"

```
Array
(

    [email] => someone@gmail.com
    [name] => Array
        (
            [first] => Joe
            [last] => Smith
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [addr_line1] => 123 Main street
            [addr_line2] => Street Address Line 2
            [city] => New Port Richey
            [state] => Florida
            [postal] => 33699
        )

   
    [position_wanted] => Array
        (
            [0] => Foster
            [1] => Adoption
        )

    [jf_app_id] => 020054
)
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

> so this is an array within an array?

Yes, it simply is :-)

> How do I reference them in PHP - the simlest way?

Indeed, display like this:

```
echo $_POST['name']['first'];
```

e.g.

```
echo 'His name is '.$_POST['name']['first']
    .', he lives in '.$_POST['address']['city'];
```

Reference:

```
// Will show „Joe”
echo $_POST['name']['first'];
echo "\n";

$name = &$_POST['name']['first'];
$name = 'Bill';

// Will show „Bill”
echo $_POST['name']['first'];
```